# Why did early pioneers in polio research not win a nobel?

Tags: nobel-prize

If we consider the two early pioneers in the fight against the polio desease to be Dr Jonas Salk and Dr Albert Sabin, why then did they not win Nobel Prizes?

Seems to me to be enough of a tremendous medical breaktrough that it was deserving of one.

Maybe these doctors were part of a team deserving the credit, but I find it odd that such a landmark medical discovery was not credit with such a prize.

Comment: It is my impression that the majority of Nobel prizes for Medicine are awarded for basic biological research not the implementation of that research in humans.

Comment: Some early pioneers in polio research did win a Nobel prize: https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/medicine/1954/summary/

Comment: Idk why google then not gives you the nobel winning polio researcher when you do a search for early pioneers in polio research.

Comment: I apologise for the false premise of this question. Seems like I was led astray by the google bot.

Comment: I think the @MichaelE2 comment is the answer.  The Nobel prize went for fundamental work which preceded the vaccines.

Comment: Actually, the premise is not entirely false, *some* polio pioneers were not awarded the prize for obscure reasons, see [Norrby-Prusiner, Polio and Nobel prizes](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17469121/):"*Another peculiar feature of the 1954 Prize is that Weller and Robbins were included based on only two nominations submitted for the first time that year... We can only speculate on why later nominations highlighting the contributions of scientists such as Jonas Salk, Hilary Koprowski, and Albert Sabin in the development of poliovirus vaccines have not been recognized by a Nobel Prize.*"